# Prove $\bigcup_{t \in I}P(A_t) \subseteq P(\bigcup_{t \in I}A_t) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Obviously $ \{A_t\}_{t\in I} $ is basically a family of desired set.
I believe the proof must have something to do with the definition of unions and also the power sets.
I had previously proved a similar problem with almost the same structure where instead of unions, intersections were used. However, nothing came to my mind for this one.
$$\bigcup_{t \in I}P(A_t) \subseteq P(\bigcup_{t \in I}A_t) $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prove $\;A\subset B\;$ by definition: $\;\forall\,a\in A\,\;\text{also}\;a\in B\;$ , and here:

$$X\in\bigcup_{t\in I}P(A_t)\implies\exists\,t_0\in I\,\,s.t.\,\,X\in P(A_{t_0})\implies X\subset A_{t_0}\implies $$

$$\implies X\subset\bigcup_{t\in I}A_t\implies X\in P\left(\bigcup_{t\in I}A_t\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Essential is:$$A\subseteq B\implies\mathcal P(A)\subseteq\mathcal P(B)$$

For an arbitrary $t_0\in I$ we have $A_{t_0}\subseteq\bigcup_{t\in I}A_t$ so that: $$\mathcal P(A_{t_0})\subseteq\mathcal P\left(\bigcup_{t\in I}A_t\right)$$

Then consequently:$$\bigcup_{t\in I}\mathcal P(A_t)\subseteq\mathcal P\left(\bigcup_{t\in I}A_t\right)$$